# NSPredicate for @[@{@"someKey" : @"key"}] search for someKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

```
[
    {"theKeyOne"  :"One"},
    {"theKeyTwo"  :"Two"},
    {"theKeyThree":"Three"},
],
```

I want use String for predicateWithFormat to NSPredicate

for example

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ == %@)", @"theKeyTwo", @"theKeyTwo"];
```

the code, I think only output `{"theKeyTwo"  :"Two"}`

but output allInfo.

the first Index is `{"theKeyOne"  :"One"}`  !!!

I want to get `Two` for `theKeyTwo`

I just know the

> theKeyTwo

How should I use it for `NSPredicate`?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i just only know theKeyTwo. I want use `NSPredicate` search the Array get the `{"theKeyTwo" : "Two"}` not `{"theKeyOne":"One"}`

Comment: @由振北 try this.. `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ == %@)", @"theKeyTwo", @"Two"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, try with this :)

```
    NSMutableDictionary *object1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [object1 setValue: @"One" forKey: @"theKeyOne"];
    [object1 setValue: @"Two" forKey: @"theKeyTwo"];
    [object1 setValue: @"Three" forKey: @"theKeyThree"];
    [object1 setValue: @"Four" forKey: @"theKeyFour"];

    // Getting the value using the key
    NSString *valueOfKey = [object1 valueForKey: @"theKeyTwo"];

    // Making the predicate using the value of key string
    NSPredicate *pred2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"theKeyTwo MATCHES[c] %@", valueOfKey];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely @Ladd.c.  I don't know 'Two', I just know `theKeyTwo`. So I cannot use `”@"theKeyTwo MATCHES[c] %@“ @"Two"`

Comment: Hi, I simplified my answer to get a value string using the name of key you know and create a NSPredicate with that value like a parameter, I hope it helps you :)

Comment: ok, thank you answer to my question. If I understand you correctly, you want to use matches solve the {key:value}. let me see . thanks agin.....  I am not familiar with matches. I will study_ study again. : )

Answer (score 0):

The questions isn't so clear. Please pick one of my variants:

1. If you want to substitute the key in a predicate, then you should use %K. So your predicate will look like this:

   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", @"theKeyTwo", @"Two"];

The output is an array: @[@{@"theKeyTwo": @"Two"}]

2. To obtain only the value you should use valueForKeypath:

   NSArray *result = [yourArray valueForKeypath:@"theKeyTwo"]

The output is an array: @[@"Two"]

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely @Mihai D.  I just know `theKeyTwo` , I don't know `Two`. I want to get `Two`